# how to detect with javascript if browser is an android webview?

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I am creating a webapp and the user could only have acces with the android webview?
Can i detect android webview with javascript?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783185/detect-inside-android-browser-or-webview

Comment: try this library https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js

Answer (score 4):

From http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#EnablingJavaScript

> For example, if you're developing a web application that's designed specifically for the WebView in your Android application, then you can define a custom user agent string with setUserAgentString(), then query the custom user agent in your web page to verify that the client requesting your web page is actually your Android application.

Answer (score 3):

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {
  // Do something!
  // Redirect to Android-site?
  window.location = 'http://android.davidwalsh.name';
}
```

Source : http://davidwalsh.name/detect-android

Comment: browser-apps would also detected which don't using the webview

Comment: it'll also detect android browsers, question is to detect if website is running inside webview through js.

Comment: It's not the right answer it also detect browers like Firefox or Chrome as 'android' . This is the only thing that works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783185/detect-inside-android-browser-or-webview

Answer (score 2):

Why not add a secret param that you will set every time you need it?