# Determine if running inside a React Native WebView

Tags: react-native, webview

I'm currently developing a RN app using the WebView component showing a remote URI, and in the JS loaded through this URI, I would like to be able to determine if I'm inside a RN WebView or not.

Have someone already faced this issue ? 
Can someone help me ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: try this library: https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js
check for webview on android and webkit for iOS

Answer (score 5):

React Native creates a bridge to the WebView and in order to do that it overrides the value of `window.postMessage`.

They save the original implementation under `window.originalPostMessage`.

Thus you can rely on the existence of `window.originalPostMessage` to detect that you're in React Native.

The Android code that does this is [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/23d61b35fb6fdbfb84f77b6d99ff155a0ff868e6/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/webview/ReactWebViewManager.java#L320) and on iOS it's [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/26684cf3adf4094eb6c405d345a75bf8c7c0bf88/React/Views/RCTWebView.m#L313)

Answer (score 4):

You can also do something like this

`injectedJavaScript="window.isRNWebView=true"`

Comment: You may also want to add `injectedJavaScriptBeforeContentLoaded` too. Somehow it didn't inject the JS code on the first load.

Answer (score 0):

React Native does not do anything else other than instantiating a native WebView and setting up a communication channel to JavaScript. That means, any native solution to the problem also applies. See the following resources:

- [Detect if user is using webview for android/iOS or a regular browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37591279/detect-if-user-is-using-webview-for-android-ios-or-a-regular-browser)
- [Detect inside Android Browser or WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783185/detect-inside-android-browser-or-webview)
- [how to detect with javascript if browser is an android webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942569/how-to-detect-with-javascript-if-browser-is-an-android-webview)