# Detecting whether webview or external browser in javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect inside Android Browser or WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783185/detect-inside-android-browser-or-webview)

i want to detect whether the web page is opened in ios web view or in other extenal sample browser. how to check this on javascript code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the user-agent, there should be differences - notably, non-webview mobile devices explicitly mention Safari. The following question has some sample code that you can use to detect the difference.

[detect ipad/iphone webview via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460205/detect-ipad-iphone-webview-via-javascript)