# Force links on external site to open up outside of UIWebView on iOS or Android app

Tags: android, ios, uiwebview, android-webview

Is there a way to prevent my site from being opened inside a `UIWebView` of **any** iOS or Android app, such as formatting the URL in a special way? These are apps that I do not own, so the call is coming from my page, not from the app.

Preferably, when an app tries to open the page on my site from within the `UIWebView`, it would automatically open up the page in the Safari or native browser app instead of inside the users application.

Otherwise, it looks like I would have to [run some javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783185/detect-inside-android-browser-or-webview) to determine if the page is opened inside of a `UIWebView` and then just restrict access.

Comment: A -1 without a comment deserves it's own -1...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. A browser is just an app. There is no specific distinction between a browser app using a webview and another app. That link for javascript browser detection will be pretty much useless for this scenario. Apps can set their user agents to whatever they want, including a user agent identical to what the native browser app uses. Essentially anything that you try to use to detect the default browser can be mimicked by another app.

Answer (score -1):

You could change the user agent in your own app to something specific that you could then detect with javascript.

You can also call javascript functions in the webview from your iOS code so you could potentially wait to display things until that call comes from your app.

While these things can be easily mimicked, and wouldnt block a scraper that ignores javascript, it's unlikely someone will go through all the trouble. If you want further protection, you'll have to introduce some form of authentication.

Comment: -1, I specifically said that "these are apps that I do not own, so the call is coming from my page, not from the app."

Comment: I was suggesting that you allow access from your own app only (by changing the user agent), while blocking access from any other apps that do not set the UA.