# From an HTML document, how to determine if it's loaded in a web view

Tags: javascript, html, webview

Suppose I have an HTML document, that is available at some URL.

Is it generally possible, for most common cases, to determine whether the documented has been loaded at root level of a web view?

The "most common case" here being a web view of an iOS or Android application. It's enough if I can only determine running inside those. This determination process is expected to be possible from JavaScript (mainly because I don't think any other page content can be useful in this).

I only care about the root level of a web view, meaning that if the page is loaded into a frame within a web view, it's a separate handling case.

No help is expected to be provided by web views, i.e. it's a black box web view.

Here is a mock of what I would like to happen:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.contentWindow) {
  alert("I'm in an iframe");
} else if (inWebView()) {
  alert("I'm in a web view");
} else {
  alert("I'm most likely in a web browser");
}
</script>
```

The check can be reversed - instead of testing for whether the container is a web view, I can test if a container is a well known web browser, but then I will need to check for all of them, desktop included.

Comment: The closest answer I've found for this is here... [for iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10170885/215821) and [for android](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6835552/215821)