# Is there a way to detect in-app mobile browser vs actual mobile browser without user-agent?

Tags: android, ios

I have a javascript file that needs to executed, when only in mobile browser and not in any (mobile) in-app browser!

Is there a way to find when a request is made from  in-app browser and when from an "actual" browser inside a mobile.

I have seen solutions with user agent! However I wanted to know if there's any better way other than using user agent/ app info to know about web view

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783185/detect-inside-android-browser-or-webview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460205/detect-ipad-iphone-webview-via-javascript

Comment: You need to search before posting questions. I found that stuff in minutes. Read this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: You would be better of doing feature detection rather than browser detection.