# How to detect Mobile Native App - web view mode to show hide html element

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have HTML adaptive page that user can directly access through the any web or mobile browser. Same HTML page I want to run as a Mobile Native App - as a web view mode and want to hide html header part with Jquery. Please help me out.

Comment: Do you have any control over this hative app, or Is third party going to load your page in their app..? If you have control, how are you going to create this native app..? What framework are you going to use..? You should provide further information.

Comment: Yes third party going to load my html in their Mobile App and want to hide header area....can I control it through the Jquery. I want to maintain single html for all (Web/Mobile Browser and Native App)

Comment: try combining http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460205/detect-ipad-iphone-webview-via-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783185/detect-inside-android-browser-or-webview. You'll have to handle other OS if required. I don't think there's a standard way that works across OS