# How to detect whether my website is loaded within an Android Webview with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm currently using the below Javascript to check if my website is loaded within an iOS webview:

```
/(iPhone|iPod|iPad).*AppleWebKit(?!.*Safari)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
```

Although, how can I check if my website is loaded within an Android Webview?

Comment: Did you see [Detect inside Android Browser or WebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783185/detect-inside-android-browser-or-webview)

Comment: @Tushar - Looks like that's exactly what I'm after. Searched high and low, can't believe I didn't come across that. Thanks for the point in the right direction.