# how to detect website open in webview or browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-studio, webview

I want the JavaScript code for checking whether a website is open in webview (in application webview) or mobile Browser (like google chrome, uc browser).

I referred to these links: But it's not working for me ..

Detect inside Android Browser or WebView

Comment: Possible duplicate of [detect ipad/iphone webview via javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460205/detect-ipad-iphone-webview-via-javascript)

Comment: From Lollipop, android is providing a way to distinguish between WebView and browser with UserAgent property, you can check from "wv" value in UserAgent if it is WebView. For more go through [this link](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent)

Answer (score 0):

**Activity -> onCreate**

```
this.webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(
    this.webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString() 
    + " "
    + getString(R.string.user_agent_suffix)
);
```

**Res -> Values -> strings.xml**

```
<string name="user_agent_suffix">AppName/1.0</string>
```

**Javascript**

```
function() isNativeApp {
    return /AppName\/[0-9\.]+$/.test(navigator.userAgent);
}
```

copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6835552/4575744)