# How to detect whether a website is loaded from an android webview

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I have a responsive website with an app (just android webviews) and apart from Google play store I want to put a download button for my app on the website. The problem is this button will show in a regular browser and still show within the app which has already been downloaded. Is there a way for me to detect that the website is loaded from my app (android webview) in order not to show the download button again? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @f-e-noel-nfebe, Is any solution you found for this problem. If yes can share a sample code in this page. I am also looking for same solution

Comment: @KrishnaMani please check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783185/detect-inside-android-browser-or-webview

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by css and media queries or JQuery/Javascript. 

Check out this thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10364620/3330058 has everything you need to know. You need to change your website's code not the android application.